Group of order $2^3 \cdot 7^2$ has a normal subgroup of order $7$ or $49$
Let $G$ be a group of order $392 = 2^3 \cdot 7^2$, then $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $7$ or $49$.
Attempt.
Suppose $G$ does not have a normal subgroup of order $49$. Then in particular, $n_7 \neq 1$. Then $n_7 = 8$. This induces a homomorphism $\varphi: G \to S_8$. And so
$$G / \ker \varphi \cong \varphi(G) \leq S_8$$
$$\implies \frac{2^3 \cdot 7^2}{|\ker \varphi|} \mid 8 \cdot 7 \cdot \dots \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$
which means that $7 \mid |\ker \varphi|$ and also $7^2 \nmid |\ker \varphi|$ by hypothesis. I have a suspicion that $|\ker \varphi| = 7$, but I'm failing to show it. If I can show that $2 \nmid |\ker \varphi|$, then I would have my result. Any sugestions?

The image of $\varphi$ has $8$ Sylow $7$-subgroups, so has order divisible by $8$.

Another way is to use the stronger form of Sylow's theorem: since $8\not\equiv1\pmod{49}$, there must be two Sylow 7-subgroups $P$ and $Q$ that have intersection of size $7$. Cardinality then implies the normalizer of $P\cap Q$ (which contains $P$ and $Q$) is the whole group $G$.

Denote the kernel by $N$. This is the intersection of the stabilizers of all $7$-Sylow subgroups. So if we fix a $7$-Sylow subgroup $P$, and let $G_P=\{g\in G: gPg^{-1}=P\}$ be its stabilizer, then $N\leq G_P$. By the orbit-stabilizer theorem (and the Sylow theorems which in particular say that the orbit of $P$ has size $8$) we know that $|G_P|=49$. Thus, $|N|$ divides $49$.
Now, $|N|$ can't be $49$ because we assume $G$ doesn't have normal subgroups of order $49$, and $|N|$ can't be $1$ because this would mean $\varphi$ is injective, which can't be the case because $|G|$ doesn't divide $|S_8|=8!$. So we must have $|N|=7$.
